# Как поменять цвет не активной кнопки?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как поменять цвет не активной кнопки?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406878/wpf-disabled-buttons-background

Comment: вы используете WPF как Winforms, не проще ли было бы тогда писать под формы и не мучаться с WPF? Второе - никогда не вставляйте свой код в конструктор окна. Раз уж на то пошло, используйте обработчик события `Window.Loaded`.

Comment: `btnManeger.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FAC716"));`